# Showing that there are no non-trivial stationary measures on the integers with respect to a spacial homogeneous walk.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

A walk on the integers $\mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots, -2,-1,0,1,2, \ldots\}$ is said to be spatially homogeneous if for $ij$th entry of the transition matrix $P$, we have that $p_{ij}=\mu(j-i)$ for some probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Z}$. Another way to think of this is that for an initial distribution $\mu$, we have that the transition probability $p(i,j) = \mu(j-i)$.

**I want to show that if we assume that $\mu(0) \neq 1$ then no stationary process exists.**

One approach that I've tried, is that if we assume the existence of a stationairy distribution $\pi$ where $\pi(0) \neq 1$, then the random variables $X_{n}$ which dictate the position, we have that
$E(X_{0})=E(X_{n})$ for any $n$, since $\pi$ is stationary
also, we have that $Var(X_{0})=Var(X_{n})$, for any $n$. But I don't quite see a contradiction.

Comment: The variance would increase with each step, but that does in itself not exclude a stationary distribution with infinite variance (or undefined expectation)

Comment: I thought for stationary processes the variance is constant? You mean generally, regardless of the distribution. Another way to do this is to perhaps write out the balance equations. Perhaps show that such a thing could not be a probability measure, I think that’s what you mean by undefined expectation.